# Poetry install crashes with packages from git

Tags: python-3.x, git, python-poetry

We use deploy with git push using gitreceive[0]
Git receive uses a pre-receive hook to execute poetry.
One of our dependencies is pulled from github.

Poetry crashes during the installation. This only happens when called using the pre-recieve hook.
Calling it as the user itself won't result in a crash.

Pipenv had no problems with this.

What can I do to fix this?

```
$ git push test test
Enumerating objects: 22, done.
Counting objects: 100% (22/22), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 19.33 KiB | 9.67 MiB/s, done.
Total 19 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0)
----> Deploying app...
Virtualenv app-py3.6 already exists.
Using virtualenv: /home/git/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/app-py3.6
Installing dependencies from lock file
remote:                                                                        
remote: [CalledProcessError]                                    
remote: Command '['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/rvanlaar/django-tls', '/tmp/py                             
remote: poetry-git-django-tlsif0u0cp9']' returned non-zero exit status 128.  
remote:                                                                        
remote: Exception trace:
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cleo/application.py in run() at line 94
remote:    status_code = self.do_run(input_, output_)
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/poetry/console/application.py in do_run() at line 88
remote:    return super(Application, self).do_run(i, o)
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cleo/application.py in do_run() at line 197
remote:    status_code = command.run(input_, output_)
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/poetry/console/commands/command.py in run() at line 77
remote:    return super(BaseCommand, self).run(i, o)
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cleo/commands/base_command.py in run() at line 146
remote:    status_code = self.execute(input_, output_)
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cleo/commands/command.py in execute() at line 107
remote:    return self.handle()
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/poetry/console/commands/install.py in handle() at line 55
remote:    return_code = installer.run()
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/poetry/installation/installer.py in run() at line 73
remote:    self._do_install(local_repo)
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/poetry/installation/installer.py in _do_install() at line 229
remote:    ops = solver.solve(use_latest=whitelist)
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/poetry/puzzle/solver.py in solve() at line 38
remote:    packages, depths = self._solve(use_latest=use_latest)
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/poetry/puzzle/solver.py in _solve() at line 171
remote:    self._package, self._provider, locked=locked, use_latest=use_latest
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/poetry/mixology/__init__.py in resolve_version() at line 7
remote:    return solver.solve()
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/poetry/mixology/version_solver.py in solve() at line 79
remote:    next = self._choose_package_version()
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/poetry/mixology/version_solver.py in _choose_package_version() at line 354
remote:    packages = self._provider.search_for(dependency)
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/poetry/puzzle/provider.py in search_for() at line 133
remote:    packages = self.search_for_vcs(dependency)
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/poetry/puzzle/provider.py in search_for_vcs() at line 174
remote:    git.clone(dependency.source, tmp_dir)
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/poetry/vcs/git.py in clone() at line 45
remote:    return self.run("clone", repository, str(dest))
remote:  /home/git/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/poetry/vcs/git.py in run() at line 101
remote:    subprocess.check_output(["git"] + list(args), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
remote:  /usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in check_output() at line 356
remote:    **kwargs).stdout
remote:  /usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in run() at line 438
remote:    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
remote: 
remote: install [--no-dev] [--dry-run] [-E|--extras EXTRAS] [--develop DEVELOP]
remote: 
To test.example.com:app
 ! [remote rejected] test -> test (pre-receive hook declined)
```

[0]https://github.com/progrium/gitreceive

Comment: What happens if execute the following: `git clone https://github.com/rvanlaar/django-tls /tmp/pypoetry-git-django-tlsif0u0cp9`